# Image in Div will not fill the whole div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I cant seem to be able to get the image of the person on the right side of the website to filll the remaining space, its a css issue but cant work it out.

Then obviosuly I need the whole thing to be able to be responsive, whicb it is, but this image also, in that it fills the space it has.

```
<div class="wp-block-column is-layout-flow">
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img decoding="async" src="https://www.accend4web.co.uk/morgiou/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/home-person-test-1.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-69" srcset="https://www.accend4web.co.uk/morgiou/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/home-person-test-1.jpg 1000w, https://www.accend4web.co.uk/morgiou/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/home-person-test-1-300x150.jpg 300w, https://www.accend4web.co.uk/morgiou/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/home-person-test-1-768x384.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="500"></figure>
</div>

@media (min-width: 782px)
.wp-block-columns:not(.is-not-stacked-on-mobile) > .wp-block-column {
flex-basis: 0;
flex-grow: 1;
}

.entry-content .wp-block-image img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Home Page](https://www.accend4web.co.uk/morgiou/)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change height of the image and its container to 100%. object-fit fills up the space correctly then.

Currently your `<figure>` doesn't have a height, and `img` has a height of auto. `object-fit: cover;` is doing it's job here, but since the image height is `auto`, the height of the image (and filled space) is proportional to the image width. By making the image and it's container's heights 100%, you tell the image to take up the whole space, and then it runs `object-fit: cover;` to fill the whole space.

```css
.wp-block-image {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  height: 100%;
}
.entry-content .wp-block-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I visited the site and tried some solutions. The problem is your div's resolution is 632x996 while that of your image is 632x316.

Because your div's height is larger than your image's, it's not possible to fit the image entirely preserving it. You could try the following:

```
.image-container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will cut the image a bit but I think you could adjust the resolution of your image accordingly.

Comment: Object-fit does this without the need for any hacky CSS. This will create a brittle solution while object-fit will be clean and easier to update/understand in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).